# Makefile: Error while compiling src and test directories

Tags: c++, makefile

```
LIB_DIRS = abcd xyz pqr mnq ghj

SER_DIRS = klm

.PHONY: default build lib service clean distclean

TEST_DIRS = abcd xyz pqr

test_lib :
        for dir in $(TEST_DIRS); do \
                $(MAKE) -C $$dir; \
        done

TESTS := $(addprefix TEST_, $(TEST_DIRS))

run : $(TESTS)

TEST_%:
        ./$*/test/$*_test --log_level=message

test :  test_lib run

default: all

all: build lib service

lib: 
        for dir in $(LIB_DIRS); do \
                $(MAKE) -C $$dir; \
        done
```

Each LIB_DIR has a src and test directory. With  the `make all` command only src directories files should get compiled. But in my case the test directories files also get compiled along with src directories. While with `make test` command only test directories files get compiled. Since test files are dependent on src files, errors occur with `make all` for test files. Can some one help me resolve this?

Comment: It appears that the src directories are `abcd`, `xyz` and `pqr`; the test directories are also `abcd`, `xyz` and `pqr`. And you want to compile files in the src directories, but not in the test directories?

Comment: Yes. When I say `make all` only the `src` directories should be compiled. And when I say `make test` only the `test` directories should be compiled.

Comment: I think what Beta is asking is, what are the `src` directories?  You keep using that term but there's nothing in your makefile related to `src`.  By `src` do you mean the `lib` target and contents of the `LIB_DIRS` variable?  What errors occur?  Do you mean that the test directories are being built before the `src` directories?  Your question is confusing and it's not clear exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. Yes `src` means LIB_DIRS and `test` means TEST_DIRS. The `test` directories are getting compiled before the `src` dirs.

Comment: In your edit you added two directories to `LIB_DIRS`, but the problem still remains: **you say you want to compile one set of directories and not another set, but one is a subset of the other.** The directory `abcd` is a member of LIB_DIRS and also a member of TEST_DIRS; all the gods of Olympus cannot compile one but not the other, it is **IMPOSSIBLE**, and I am voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a starter:

You should provide Makefiles in each directory that know how to build `lib` and `test`. Obviously `test` depends on `lib`.

You could then change your lines to

```
lib: 
    for dir in $(LIB_DIRS); do \
            $(MAKE) -C $$dir; \
    done
```

to

```
lib: 
    for dir in $(LIB_DIRS); do \
            $(MAKE) -C $$dir lib; \ #<- notice the target
    done
```

and similar for `test_lib`. Otherwise, it is not possible with the current set of variables since the sub-make does not know what to do.